# Compactness of a subset of $C[-1,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

Consider $C[-1,1]$ with the supremum norm and $M$ a subset,

$M=\{f\in C[-1,1]:|f(0)-\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx|\leq 1\}.$

Is $M$ compact? I have already proved it is closed but I am having trouble with compactness.

Comment: Is the integration from $-1$ to $1$ or from $0$ to $1$?

Comment: I have edited the post. The space is $C[-1.1]$

Comment: By the same reason as in the answer of @K.Power, $M$ is noncompact.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}nx+n&x\in[-1,0)\\ -nx+n & x\in[0,1]\end{cases}.$$
Then every subsequence of $(f_{n})$ tends to infinity in norm, so $(f_n)$ has no convergent subsequences. However $|f_n(0)-\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx|=0$ for every $n\in \mathbb N$. Thus $M$ can't be compact. You can easily adapt this proof for $C[a,b]$.

Comment: @mathsisfunnn The same idea works, look at my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a  normed linear space and let $G:X\to \Bbb R$ or $G:X\to\Bbb C$ be a non-zero bounded linear functional. Then $G^{-1}\{0\}$ is a vector subspace of $X$ of co-dimension $1.$ That is, if $f\in X$ and $G(f)\ne 0$ then the vector space generated by $\{f\}\cup G^{-1}\{0\}$ is all of $X.$ In particular if $X$ is not $1$-dimensional then the vector space $G^{-1}\{0\}$ is not $\{0\}$ and therefore it is an unbounded subset of $X.$

In your Q, $X=C[-1,1]$ and $G(f)=f(0)-\int_{-1}^1f(t)dt.$ Now $G^{-1}[-1,1]$ is unbounded, and hence is not compact, as it has an unbounded subset $G^{-1}\{0\}$.

Comment: The first paragraph even applies when  $G $ is not bounded.